# Progress bar threading in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Threading
Public Class frmPurchaseAnalysis
    Dim dA1 As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dS1 As New DataSet
    Dim fmRptStr As String
    Dim lCnt As Integer
    Dim stritm As String
    Dim strwrk As String


    Private Sub frmPurchaseAnalysis_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load



        'Itemmtype
        dA1 = New SqlDataAdapter("Select ItemTypeID,ItemType from ItemTypeRoot order by ItemTypeID ", cnnDbOne)
        dA1.Fill(dS1)
        cmbItemType.Items.Add("Select ItemType")

        For lCnt = 0 To dS1.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            SmQryStr = Mid(dS1.Tables(0).Rows(lCnt)("ItemType"), 1, 30)
            SmQryStr &= Space(31 - SmQryStr.Length) & dS1.Tables(0).Rows(lCnt)("ItemTypeID")
            cmbItemType.Items.Add(SmQryStr)
        Next
        cmbItemType.SelectedIndex = 0
        dS1.Clear()
        dA1.Dispose()

    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdExit.Click
        Me.Dispose()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Public Sub cmdView_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdView.Click
        Dim Obj1 As New Thread(AddressOf T1)
        Dim Obj2 As New Thread(AddressOf T2)
        Obj1.Start()
        Obj2.Start()

        Dim strwrk As String
        strwrk = txtdays.Text
        If cmbItemType.Text <> "Select ItemType" And cmbItemType.Text <> "" Then
            stritm = Mid(cmbItemType.Text, 32)
        End If
        SmSqlCmd = New SqlCommand
        SmSqlCmd.Connection = cnnDbOne
        SmSqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 200
        SmSqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        SmSqlCmd.CommandText = "Rpt_PurchaseAnalysis"
        SmSqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemType", stritm)
        SmSqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Targetdays", strwrk)
        SmSqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", Format(DTP2.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy"))

        dA1 = New SqlDataAdapter(SmSqlCmd)
        dS1.Clear()
        dA1.Fill(dS1)



    End Sub
    Private Sub T1()
        Dim i As Integer
        i += 1
        PrgrsBar.Value = i
        If PrgrsBar.Value = PrgrsBar.Maximum Then

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub T2()

        Dim SmReport As ReportDocument
        Try
            SmReport = New RptPurchaseAnalysis
            SmReport.SetDataSource(dS1.Tables(0))
            SmReport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("StartDate").Text = """" + Format(DTP1.Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy") + """"
            SmReport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("enddate").Text = """" + Format(DTP2.Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy") + """"

            Dim frmRptViewer As New frmRptViewer
            frmRptViewer.CrRptVwer1.ReportSource = SmReport
            frmRptViewer.Show()
            dS1.Clear()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Some Reporting Error Has Been Occured. " + vbCrLf + ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Sales Statistics Reporting")
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

**Tell Me where i did the wrong code??? i want to show progressbar increasing while my report has been loaded**

Answer (score 2):

You have to be careful when you deal with GUI and threads.

Accessing Windows Forms controls is not inherently thread safe. If you have two or more threads manipulating the state of a control, it is possible to force the control into an inconsistent state.

The easiest way to update controls in another thread is to use the [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hybbz6ke.aspx). You can read more in this [article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker).

```
class Program
{
  static BackgroundWorker _bw = new BackgroundWorker();

  static void Main()
  {
    _bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
    _bw.RunWorkerAsync ("Message to worker");
    Console.ReadLine();
  }

  static void bw_DoWork (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {
    // This is called on the worker thread
    Console.WriteLine (e.Argument);        // writes "Message to worker"
    // Perform time-consuming task...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see (at least) the following problems in your code:

- You are doing the lengthy operation (loading the data from the database) in the main thread. That's wrong. Since only the main thread can update the UI, you need to do your ProgressBar stuff in the main thread and the database operation in a background thread.
- At the beginning of `cmdView_Click`, you are starting Thread T2, which reads `dS1`. However, `dS1` is not available yet, since it's just being filled in the main thread.
- I don't quite understand what you are trying to do in T1: You initialize i (to 0), then you increase it to 1 (`i += 1`), then you execute an empty `if` statement...

My suggestion would be that you have a deep look at one of the online tutorials of showing a progress bar in WinForms while performing a background operation, read it until you understand it fully (feel free to ask a more specific question on StackOverflow here, if you don't understand parts of it), and then try again.